# Scrolling image inside ScrollViewer on tablet (Windows Store app, C#)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

Inside ScrollViewer control I have a large image and I want to use scroll bars to move that image inside ScrollViewer. See XAML code below:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="282" Width="554" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
  <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Source="Assets/big_image.jpg" Stretch="None" ManipulationMode="None"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This works fine on my PC. I can use mouse to move image inside ScrollViewer by using scrollbars. But when I deploy application on the tablet, I cannot do anything. The scrollbars are not visible and I cannot use gestures to manipulate the image. Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I haven't got to target the tablets as much Id like yet, but I think just adding a background to the `ScrollViewer` will flip the IsHitTestVisible of its contents to True for the gestures. So just a quick Background="White", give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Microsoft example with similar functionality:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-ScrollViewer-pan-and-949d29e9

This example uses a `Scrollviewer` with an inside image to show the capabilities of the `ScrollViewer` control to pan and zoom. I tried it with a tablet and it works well.

Hope it helps.